# Connect automatically to VPN when connecting to wifi access point?

Tags: macos, wifi, vpn

Is it possible to automatically connect to a VPN when one is connected to a WIFI access point?

To manually connect to a VPN after connecting to a WIFI access point works, but it is so easy to forget.

I am using Mavericks on a Macbook Pro Retina.

Comment: [This](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/422957/373466) is how you can do it on iPhone/iOS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## [ControlPlane](http://www.controlplaneapp.com)

You want to have an automated action after you connect to a certain WiFi point. An easy way to do this, is using ControlPlane (formally known as MarcoPolo). This software makes your computer context aware and can execute scripts and programs when your location changes. Some examples that ControlPlane is aware of:

- Current Audio Output device (headphones/internal speakers)
- Discoverable Bluetooth devices
- Advertised Bonjour (Zeroconf) services
- Attached FireWire devices
- Assigned IP addresses
- Ambient Light level
- Attached Monitors
- Active Network Links
- Power source (power adapter/battery)
- Running Applications
- Current Time Of Day
- Attached USB devices
- Visible WiFi networks

**edit** (21 aug 2014, thanks to @Rainer):
Marcopolo is now [ControlPlane](http://www.controlplaneapp.com).
ControlPlane was created using code from version 2.5.1 of the MarcoPolo project still available at http://www.symonds.id.au/marcopolo/.  ControlPlane is a direct port of MarcoPolo and in fact, much of the configuration from MarcoPolo still works with ControlPlane, just better!

ControlPlane supports 32 and 64bit Intel based Macs running Snow Leopard through Lion.

Comment: That's an idea! But it seems that Marcopolo is  it maintained anymore and the author suggests using controlplne instead  http://www.controlplaneapp.com/ I will look at it again. Thanks.

Comment: Ok - got it working with using ControlPlane, Tunnelblick for the VPN connection and AppleScript to connect and disconnect the VPN.

Comment: @Rainer can you post that script?

Comment: Sorry - Not usine it anymore and lost it.

Comment: The applescript to connect to Tunnelblick

`tell application "Tunnelblick"
 connect ("pfwtracs01-udp-1194-config")
end tell`