# How can I securely deploy a configuration profile to an iPhone without another Apple device?

Tags: iphone, ios, configuration-profiles

I have an iPhone that is not managed by an organization. By using configuration profiles, I want to apply settings that cannot be set via the GUI. Those settings contain passwords and therefore I need a secure way to transfer the configuration profiles to my iPhone.

As I do not have access to other Apple devices, what possibilities do I have?

Comment: Do you want to know how to create the configuration profiles or just how to distribute it? Or both?

Comment: This question is *just* about the secure deployment/distribution of configuration profiles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/business/documentation/Configuration-Profile-Reference.pdf)...

> There are five ways to deploy configuration profiles:
>
> - Using [Apple Configurator 2](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/apple-configurator-2/id1037126344?mt=12),
>   available in the App Store
> - In an email message
> - On a webpage
> - Using over-the-air configuration as described in [Over-the-Air Profile Delivery and
>   Configuration](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/iPhoneOTAConfiguration/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009505)
> - Over the air using a Mobile Device Management Server

As *Apple Configurator* is only available for macOS and both *Over-the-Air Profile Delivery* and *MDM solutions* are solutions for enterprises, you are probably left with e-mail message or a webpage.

You can of course also use any 3rd party app that offers some sort of file sharing/synchronization. But as you want to transfer sensitive information, make sure you use an app with end-to-end encryption, where you are the single owner of the encryption keys.

## Via e-mail

You can easily send a configuration profile via e-mail. As soon as you click on the attachment, it will be loaded and you can [install](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT209435) it from the Settings app.

But as you want to transfer it securely, a simple e-mail won't do it. Again, you need end-to-end encryption because the file will travel through the internet. You can achieve that by setting up [S/MIME for your e-mail](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202345), for example. But I am not sure, if you can do it already as a consumer with the Apple mail app. You might need a 3rd party app for that.

## Via webpage

It sounds like an overkill, but that can be done easily and securely with free open source tools and just your laptop. Steps you need:

1. Interconnect your laptop and iPhone via WiFi (ad hoc network, no router needed, just the two devices)
2. Setup a temporary HTTPS web server with Python to serve the configuration profile
3. ???
4. Profit: Access the configuration profile securely through Safari on your iPhone

This is how you can do it with a Windows laptop:

1. [Create a wireless ad hoc network](https://superuser.com/a/1658425/1077440). Use `ipconfig` afterwards to determine the IP address of your laptop for this network.
2. Connect your iPhone to this network, as you would with any other WiFi.
3. Create a self signed certificate that you will need for your web server. You can use `OpenSSL` for example. You already got that, if you have [Git for Windows](https://git-scm.com/download/win) installed. You find it at `<GIT_INSTALL_PATH>\bin` or `<GIT_INSTALL_PATH>\mingw64\bin`. To create that certificate, just execute:

   ```
   .\openssl.exe req -new -newkey rsa:4096 -x509 -keyout localhost.pem -out localhost.pem -nodes
   ```
4. Create the following folder structure to serve your configuration profile from:

   ```
   /
   └── www/
       ├── html/
       │   └── MyConfigProfile.mobileconfig
       └── localhost.pem
   ```
5. Use `html` as your working directory and use [Python 3 to start a HTTPS web server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19706670/11942268) from there. Replace `<IP>` by the IP address you retrieved in step 1. You can also adjust the port address (2021), if you want:

   ```
   import http.server, ssl

   server_address = ('<IP>', 2021)
   httpd = http.server.HTTPServer(server_address, http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler)
   httpd.socket = ssl.wrap_socket(httpd.socket, server_side=True, certfile='../localhost.pem', ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS)
   httpd.serve_forever()
   ```
6. On your iPhone, open Safari and access `https://<IP>:2021/MyConfigProfile.mobileconfig` (replace `<IP>` by the IP address you retrieved in step 1). As you are using a self signed certificate, Safari cannot verify it and will complain. This is normally a security concern, but as you are the owner of both sides it is totally fine. To be 100% sure you can just compare the certificate shown on your iPhone with the one you generated on your laptop. You can then proceed to [install](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT209435) the configuration profile.

Comment: I wonder what the point is of HTTPS here. What are you defending against? That someone else is in the same hotspot and sniffing the data? If someone is, they could just access the same address too and then Python will happily list files, allowing them to easily browse to whichever file it can serve. OTOH it's to prevent an MITM of some sort, then you *definitely* should be inspecting the certificate shown on the phone.

Comment: Yes, if someone can access the temporary WiFi, while you are using it, he can sure also access the sensitive file. HTTPS helps in that case, that an eavesdropper just records your wireless traffic and decrypts it later, then he won't be able to read the transfered and TLS-encrypted file.

Comment: Anybody capable of listening in at that time should also be perfectly capable of connecting to the WiFi. Ad-hoc WiFi security has been pretty trivially crackable these days.